# MySQL CASE ELSE not returning 0 in multi join select statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a view like this:

```
VIEW `my_view` AS (
SELECT 
    t1.sku AS sku,
    FORMAT(SUM((CASE
            WHEN (t3.order_date > (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 42 DAY)) THEN t2.qty
            ELSE 0
        END)),
        0) AS qty_sold,
    FORMAT(SUM((CASE
            WHEN (t3.order_status_id = 3) THEN t2.qty
            ELSE 0
        END)),
        0) AS qty_ordered
FROM
    inventory_products t1
    JOIN inventory_sales t2 ON (t2.sku = t1.sku)
    JOIN inventory_orders t3 ON (t3.id = t2.order_id)
where t1.sku=1001 or t1.sku=1002 or t1.sku=1010
    GROUP BY t1.sku
)
```

The view works as expected, and returns correct results, except that when a `sku` doesn't exist on the `inventory_sales` table, the row for that sku doesn't return at all.

Note that the `sku=1010` doesn't exist on the `inventory_sales` table, but it does exist on the `inventory_products` table.

for example:

```
SELECT * FROM my_view 
WHERE sku=1001 OR sku=1002 OR sku=1010
```

returns this:

```
+-----------+--------------+------------+
|    sku    |   qty_sold   |qty_ordered |   
+-----------+--------------+------------+
|   1001    |      2       |     2      |
+-----------+--------------+------------+
|   1002    |      3       |     3      |
+-----------+--------------+------------+
```

but I need it to return this:

```
+-----------+--------------+------------+
|    sku    |   qty_sold   |qty_ordered |   
+-----------+--------------+------------+
|   1001    |      2       |     2      |
+-----------+--------------+------------+
|   1002    |      3       |     3      |
+-----------+--------------+------------+
|   1010    |      0       |     0      |
+-----------+--------------+------------+
```

What am I missing here?  Any advice would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need `left join`:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM inventory_products t1 LEFT JOIN
     inventory_sales t2
     ON t2.sku = t1.sku LEFT JOIN
     inventory_orders t3
     ON t3.id = t2.order_id
WHERE t1.sku IN (1001, 1002, 1010)
GROUP BY t1.sku
```

I think the `ELSE 0` will turn the `NULL` into a `0` -- your desired result.

Comment: Thanks!  Originally I was using `LEFT JOIN`, so I'm not sure what I changed to break it.